# How do I copy a Table column and paste it into another table column on another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, range, excel-tables, listobject

I have two worksheets. I enter weekly numbers into a column on one sheet and at the end of the week I copy those numbers to a table column on the other sheet. I clear the contents and start with new numbers in same column. I would like a macro to do this. Simply recording a macro has not worked.

[image]

[image]

I also have a reference in cell "F2" that I would like to use that names the column in the table I want to copy too. Thanks.

This is what I tried

```
  Range("TM[Net]").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("C").Select
    Range("D2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, 
Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("H9").Select
    Sheets("M").Select
    Range("G5").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("C").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I have to ask, did simply recording a macro at least get you started? Best to share some code, even if it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Excel Table Data Column

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```vb
Sub CopyColumn()
    
    ' Workbook
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
        
    ' Source
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("M")
    
    Dim sHeader As String: sHeader = sws.Range("G2").Value
    If Len(sHeader) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim slo As ListObject: Set slo = sws.ListObjects("TM")
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = slo.ListColumns(sHeader).DataBodyRange
    
    ' Destination
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("C")
    Dim dHeader As String: dHeader = sws.Range("G3").Value
    If Len(sHeader) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim dlo As ListObject: Set dlo = dws.ListObjects("TC")
    Dim dfCell As Range:
    Set dfCell = dlo.ListColumns(dHeader).Range.Cells(1).Offset(1)
    Dim dcrg As Range: Set dcrg = dfCell.Resize(scrg.Rows.Count)
    
    ' Copy values.
    
    dcrg.Value = scrg.Value
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Copied from ""M!" & scrg.Address(0, 0) & """ to ""C!" _
        & dcrg.Address(0, 0) & """.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Just tried the code from VBasic2008, it didn't work. I'm not sure I made it clear what I'm trying to do. From sheet "M", column "D" which it in Table and range as "TM[Net]". I need to copy that column to sheet TC, which is also a table with table ranges by Wk?. I may need to put in Wk1 this week or Wk3 next week. So, I put the destination in sheet M cell F2. I have tried to adapt the VBA code you suggested but to no avail. It will copy to sheet C column Wk4 every time. In the end I will have about 15 Wk? columns, but they will all be filled from sheet M Column Net.

Comment: This is basically just the opposite of what you suggested a few days ago, which works great, Thanks for your help.

Comment: I abandoned the `F2` idea because if the table is empty (the data body range is nothing), e.g. `.Range("TC[Wk1]")` will raise an error. Change the value in `F2` to just the column header and replace `G3` with `F2` in my code. Also, replace `sws.Range("G2").Value` with `"Net"` and remove the line `If Len(sHeader)...`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. With the changes you suggested it works perfect. You have spent a lot of time helping me with these issues. You get my upvote.